# No graphical user interface after update on 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, gui, gdm

After an update from Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 to 16.04 my gui completly crashes after GRUB. If I try a normal boot, the gui freezes there, where the LVM needs the password to decrypt the systemdrive.

I can boot into the recoverymode and decrypt the systempartition but then strange things happends.

The gui does not start and tty1 just "flashes" every few seconds. It looks like some process try to start the gui but it does not work.

If I change to tty2 or another tty the "flash" kicks me back to tty7 every few seconds.

With `ps aux | grep Xorg` I see, that the Xorg server is restartet whenever this "flash" happens (PID is increasing every "flash"). I can just stop it by renaming the Xorg binary.

I try to install the driver from Nvidia for my GForce 980TI

http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/77844/en-us

but theres an error while building the DKMS Module.
(UEFI Secure boot is deactivated).

Edit:
Found this thread
[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)
and try the following things:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-364
```

Didn't help

```
sudo apt-get purge xorg-* xserver-xorg; sudo apt-get install xorg xserver-xorg; sudo dpkg-reconfigure xorg
```

Didn't help

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop gnome-desktop-environment; sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Didn't help

It seems like I have to do a fresh install.

Comment: You should find your answer there : http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I try everything that is mentioned there. But nothing seems to work. Maybe a fresh install of ubuntu is the only way :(

Comment: I have tried a lot of things but,
try to disable secure boot from UEFI BIOS. This fixed my problem and now is working .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try to install NVIDIA drivers 361 - open a terminal and execute the following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 2):

At first, you need to Fix compiz problem :

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
sudo rm -fr ~/.compiz
```

Then you should try this if your session not loading :

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.Xauthority
sudo rm -fr ~/.config/autostart
```

then, zou have to Reinstall compiz

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity compizconfig-settings-manager upstart
```

Finally clear the Unity Desktop :

```
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Working on Ubuntu 16.04 amd64 on Dell XPS 13 Developer edition.